Things are red when using blender 4.2 EEVEE next
On blender 4.2 I'm having this problem where all my objects are turning red when I use EEVEE. I can't figure out how to make them a normal color. I've tried changing the texture, changing the rendering settings. I don't know what to do.
Viewport, There are no nodes hooked up but its still red:

Rendered result (EEVEE):

Rendered result (Cycles):


Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

Does this also happen when you create a new file and directly render the Default Cube?

The problem is in the IOR, you must change it to 0  like this

Normally by default it is like this


Make sure you do not have multiple Material Output nodes in your shader. By default, the Material Output is set to All, however there is also the option to set it to EEVEE or Cycles:

This is helpful when you specifically want different material outputs for different render engines in a single material, to not have to switch materials when switching engines, maybe because some setting which looks good for EEVEE does not look good in Cycles and vice versa. Some shader nodes do not work in both render engines but maybe you still want to use them in case you render with the engine that can use them.
Now the three options work with this logic:

If there are specific outputs for each engine, one for EEVEE, one for Cycles and none for All, of course the output according to the engine will be used.

If there is a specific material output for e.g. EEVEE, this will be used for EEVEE, an additional one for All will be ignored and used for the other engine.

If there are three different outputs, one for EEVEE, one for Cycles and a general one for All, the general one will be completely ignored and never used.

If there are two or more outputs for the same render engine, the one that is (or was last) active is the one that is used.

If the engine is EEVEE and there are two or more e.g. outputs for EEVEE, but the active one is for Cycles or All, then the "oldest" EEVEE output will be used.


Well, images say more than 1000 words. Here are some examples. First we have a red material for EEVEE, a green one for Cycles and a blue one for All.
Not surprising, when the engine is set to EEVEE, the red material shows, set to Cycles the green material shows and the blue one does not appear at all.


But if I now get rid of the green Cycles material while the engine is set to Cycles, then the blue material for All will be used:

Back to three outputs. This time, we have the green material for Cycles, but two materials for EEVEE: red and blue. If the output of the red material is active (indicated by the bordeaux-colored label while the others are grey), the object shows red. If the blue material output is active, the object shows blue.


And now this happens when the render engine is set to EEVEE, but the active material output is the green one for Cycles: Of course EEVEE will not show the Cycles material. But it also does not keep track of which EEVEE material was active before. Instead it falls back to the EEVEE output node which is "oldest" in the nodetree. In this case the red one:

The output which is used is not determined by some alphabetical order according to how it is named or in order from left to right how they are placed in the nodetree or anything but purely on the chronology in which the nodes were added.
